# Django: Check if a user is logged in before allowing them to register?

Tags: python, django

New to Django here. I am setting up a registration page and I would like to ensure that someone who is currently logged in can't create a new account.

So far I have a form like this:

```
class RegisterView(FormView):
    template_name = 'users/register_user.html'
    success_url = 'thank_you'

    def get(self, request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            # If a user is logged in, redirect them to a page informing them of such
            return render(request, 'users/already_logged_in.html')
        else:
            # would like to direct the user to the normal registration page

    def post(self, request):
        user_form = UserCreateForm(request.POST)
        if user_form.is_valid():
            username = user_form.clean_username()
            password = user_form.clean_password2()
            user_form.save()
            user = authenticate(username=username,
                                password=password)
            login(request, user)
            return render(request, 'home.html')
        return render(request, 'register_user.html', {'form': user_form})
```

I suspect that I might have to use mixins (I'm also confused about what they are) so if they are part of the solution please expand a little bit.

What should I include after the "else" to get it to pass the usual registration page?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How about you check `user.is_authenticated()` in the template that shows registration link and just don't show it anymore if user is logged in? Otherwise it sounds like a rather poor UX :)

Comment: favoretti, fair point. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just return what the parent FormView would have returned

```
def get(self, request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        # If a user is logged in, redirect them to a page informing them of such
        return render(request, 'users/already_logged_in.html')
    else:
        return super(RegisterView, self).get(request)
```

You'll need to set form_class on your view, rather than in your post Method, look at the django docs for how to use FormView https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#formview

Comment: is_authenticated says nothing about whether the use is actually logged in. The Documentation makes it clear (from at least 1.7 onwards) that it returns True for all real users (and False for all anonymous users) regardless of the login status.